# chrome.storage.sync.set - does developer have access to this data?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking through the code for a chrome extension i use to see what data is reported back to devleoper/mother-ship.  I see that the extension's code saves some info using 'chrome.storage.sync.set' which of course makes sense as the variables that are stored there are available to me not matter what computer I load the extension on.

My question is... does the developer have access to this data?  I would guess not but wanted to make sure.   I have been looking for other code that posts data or does something that could send data back to developer but this was the only thing that looked suspicious so far.

Answer (score 3):

No, developer cannot access `chrome.storage.sync` data and no one can read this except you.

This location is access controlled by

1. User
2. Extension

Infact any other extension can not read other extension's data. You can think about this storage similar to `localstorage`.

Now, If I ask you a question

> Does the website developer has access to different values stored in user's local storage ?

The answer is No. Developer can control what to save in this storage and the values are user specific and they remain on user's machine.

However, this comes with a catch. You have to look out for code like this in the extension:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('key', function(obj) {
  // Make ajax to upload the key value pair
});
```

But by default, developer do not have access.

Comment: Thanks.. what makes that bad?  is that retrieving the 'key' and passing it another function that makes it bad? 

There is a function that gets some of the data but it appear to be restore/load this data on startup.   Is it the request for the 'key' that i should look out for. 

function restore_options() {




    chrome.storage.sync.get({
   emailAddress : "",
   updateperiod : 1,
   storefronts : []
  }, function(t) {